# My express routing not working on different discord servers

Tags: node.js, express, http, routes, discord

So what happens is I am creating a discord bot that access the routes from express and it works if I keep it on a certain server, but if I try to access express on a different server while the server is on I get
[image]

Restarting the server removes the "assignments is not a function" So this only works when I try to access these routes endpoints from a completely different server. More information, If I try to do curl requests to these endpoints with different channel or guild id information, I also get that error. So I am assuming thats where a lot of the problem is coming from. I don't know why different information throws off the function.

**index.js**

```
import express, { json, query, request, response } from 'express';
import { assignments , announcements , discussions} from "./Fetch/fetchCalls.js";
var app = express();
app.use(express.json());
const PORT = 8080;
app.listen(PORT);

var guild;
var channel;

        

  app.all('/assignments',(request) => {assignments(guild = request.body.guild, channel = request.body.channel);});
app.all('/discussions',(request) => {discussions(guild = request.body.guild,channel = request.body.channel); });
app.all('/announcements', (request) => {announcements(guild = request.body.guild,channel = request.body.channel);});
```

**fetchCalls.js**

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch';
import { createRequire } from "module";
import { getRecord, updateChannelID } from './dbUtil.js';
import { clearData } from './clear.js';
const require = createRequire(import.meta.url);
const config = require("../Canvas Bot/Source/Data/config.json")


var obj;
var course;
var url;
var access_token;
var guildid;
var channelid;


export  function discussions(guild,channel) {
  guildid = guild; 
  channelid = channel;
  discussionsFunc();
   async function discussionsFunc(){
        try {
          updateChannelID(guildid,channelid);
          await getRecord({ guild_id : `${guildid}`}, getFetchData);
          const res1 = await fetch(url + `courses/${course}/discussion_topics?scope=unlocked`, {
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
              Authorization: `Bearer ${access_token}`,
              "Content-Type": "application/json",
              
            },
          });
          const apiData = await res1.json();
          
          for(discussions of apiData){
          const string = ["**TOPIC: "+discussions.title +"**", discussions.message + "\n"];
          const res2 = await fetch(
            `https://discordapp.com/api/channels/${channelid}/messages`,
            {
              method: "POST",
              headers: {
                "Authorization": `Bot ${config.TOKEN}`, 
                Accept: "application/json",
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                
              },
              "Connection": "close",
              body: JSON.stringify({
                
                content: string.join('\n').replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/gi, "")
              }),
            }
          );
      
          const apiResponse = await res2.json();
         
          }
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
        
        
      }
      clearData();
      };

      export function announcements(guild,channel)  {
        
        guildid = guild; 
        channelid = channel;
       
        announcementsFunc();

        
         async function announcementsFunc(){
          
          
          updateChannelID(guildid,channelid);
          
        try {
          
          await getRecord({ guild_id : `${guildid}`}, getFetchData);
        
          const res1 = await fetch(url + `/announcements?context_codes[]=${obj}&latest_only=true`, {
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
              Authorization: `Bearer ${access_token}` ,
              "Content-Type": "application/json",
              
            },
          });
          const apiData = await res1.json();
          console.log(apiData);
          for( announcements of apiData){
          const string = [`\`\`\`${announcements.title}\n`, `${announcements.message}\n\`\`\``];
          const res2 = await fetch(
            `https://discordapp.com/api/channels/${channelid}/messages`,
            {
              method: "POST",
              headers: {
                "Authorization": `Bot ${config.TOKEN}`, 
                Accept: "application/json",
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                
              },
              "Connection": "close",
              body: JSON.stringify({
                
                content: string.join('\n').replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/gi, "")
              }),
            }
          );
            
          const apiResponse = await res2.json();
          console.log(apiResponse);
          }
          
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
        
        
      }

      
      clearData();
    }
   
     
      export  function assignments(guild, channel) {
        guildid = guild;
        channelid = channel;
        assignmentsFunc();
        
        
         async function assignmentsFunc(){
          updateChannelID(guildid,channelid);
        try {
          
          await getRecord({guild_id : `${guildid}`}, getFetchData);
          const res1 = await fetch(url + `/courses/${course}/assignments?order_by=due_at`, {
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
              Authorization: `Bearer ${access_token}`,
              "Content-Type": "application/json",
              
            },
          });
          const apiData = await res1.json();
          
          console.log(apiData);
          var size = apiData.length-1;
          
          
          for( assignments of apiData){
          const string = [`\`\`\`Name:   ${assignments.name}`, `Description:\n ${assignments.description}`,`Due Date:  ${assignments.due_at}\n\`\`\``];         
             const res2 = await fetch(
            `https://discordapp.com/api/channels/${channelid}/messages`,
            {
              method: "POST",
              headers: {
                "Authorization": `Bot ${config.TOKEN}`, 
                Accept: "application/json",
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                
              },
              "Connection": "close",
              body: JSON.stringify({
                
                content: string.join('\n').replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/gi, "")
              }),
            }
          );
          
      
          const apiResponse = await res2.json();
          console.log(apiResponse);
          }
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
       
        
        
      }
      clearData();
      }


       function getFetchData(document) {
         obj =  'course_' + document._courseid;
         course = document._courseid;
         course1 = "_" + course;
         url = 'https://' + document.prefix + '.instructure.com/api/v1/';
         access_token = document.access_token;
         console.log('obj = ' + obj + '\ncourse = ' + course + '\nurl = ' + url + '\naccess_token = ' + access_token);
      }
```

and if necessary

**dbUtil.js**

```
import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb';



const uri = 'cluser uri';
const client = new MongoClient(uri)



export async function updateChannelID(guildids, channelids) {
  
  try{
    await client.connect();

    // db name and collection
    const database = client.db("Users");
    const docs = database.collection("user_info");

    

    var query = {guild_id: `${guildids}`};
    var insert = {$set: {channel_id: `${channelids}`}};

    // find the first record matching the given query
    
      docs.updateOne(query,insert);

  }
  catch(error){
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the content of this file "./Fetch/fetchCalls.js" ?

Comment: Updated with all necessary files. @Ayzrian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in the `fetchCall.js` file. First of all, you are exporting things in the wrong manner. If you are not using tools like babel, syntax `export function ...` is incorrect, you have to use `module.exports` to export things from a Node.js module.

So you can change your file in the following manner, for example.

```
function discussions(guild, channel) {
    guildid = guild;
    channelid = channel;
    discussionsFunc();
    async function discussionsFunc() {
        try {
            updateChannelID(guildid, channelid);
            await getRecord({
                guild_id: `${guildid}`
            }, getFetchData);
            const res1 = await fetch(url + `courses/${course}/discussion_topics?scope=unlocked`, {
                method: "GET",
                headers: {
                    Authorization: `Bearer ${access_token}`,
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",

                },
            });
            const apiData = await res1.json();

            for (discussions of apiData) {
                const string = ["**TOPIC: " + discussions.title + "**", discussions.message + "\n"];
                const res2 = await fetch(
                    `https://discordapp.com/api/channels/${channelid}/messages`, {
                        method: "POST",
                        headers: {
                            "Authorization": `Bot ${config.TOKEN}`,
                            Accept: "application/json",
                            "Content-Type": "application/json",

                        },
                        "Connection": "close",
                        body: JSON.stringify({

                            content: string.join('\n').replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/gi, "")
                        }),
                    }
                );

                const apiResponse = await res2.json();

            }
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }


    }
    clearData();
};

function announcements(guild, channel) {

    guildid = guild;
    channelid = channel;

    announcementsFunc();


    async function announcementsFunc() {


        updateChannelID(guildid, channelid);

        try {

            await getRecord({
                guild_id: `${guildid}`
            }, getFetchData);

            const res1 = await fetch(url + `/announcements?context_codes[]=${obj}&latest_only=true`, {
                method: "GET",
                headers: {
                    Authorization: `Bearer ${access_token}`,
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",

                },
            });
            const apiData = await res1.json();
            console.log(apiData);
            for (announcements of apiData) {
                const string = [`\`\`\`${announcements.title}\n`, `${announcements.message}\n\`\`\``];
                const res2 = await fetch(
                    `https://discordapp.com/api/channels/${channelid}/messages`, {
                        method: "POST",
                        headers: {
                            "Authorization": `Bot ${config.TOKEN}`,
                            Accept: "application/json",
                            "Content-Type": "application/json",

                        },
                        "Connection": "close",
                        body: JSON.stringify({

                            content: string.join('\n').replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/gi, "")
                        }),
                    }
                );

                const apiResponse = await res2.json();
                console.log(apiResponse);
            }

        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }


    }


    clearData();
}


function assignments(guild, channel) {
    guildid = guild;
    channelid = channel;
    assignmentsFunc();


    async function assignmentsFunc() {
        updateChannelID(guildid, channelid);
        try {

            await getRecord({
                guild_id: `${guildid}`
            }, getFetchData);
            const res1 = await fetch(url + `/courses/${course}/assignments?order_by=due_at`, {
                method: "GET",
                headers: {
                    Authorization: `Bearer ${access_token}`,
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",

                },
            });
            const apiData = await res1.json();

            console.log(apiData);
            var size = apiData.length - 1;


            for (assignments of apiData) {
                const string = [`\`\`\`Name:   ${assignments.name}`, `Description:\n ${assignments.description}`, `Due Date:  ${assignments.due_at}\n\`\`\``];
                const res2 = await fetch(
                    `https://discordapp.com/api/channels/${channelid}/messages`, {
                        method: "POST",
                        headers: {
                            "Authorization": `Bot ${config.TOKEN}`,
                            Accept: "application/json",
                            "Content-Type": "application/json",

                        },
                        "Connection": "close",
                        body: JSON.stringify({

                            content: string.join('\n').replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/gi, "")
                        }),
                    }
                );


                const apiResponse = await res2.json();
                console.log(apiResponse);
            }
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }



    }
    clearData();
}


function getFetchData(document) {
    obj = 'course_' + document._courseid;
    course = document._courseid;
    course1 = "_" + course;
    url = 'https://' + document.prefix + '.instructure.com/api/v1/';
    access_token = document.access_token;
    console.log('obj = ' + obj + '\ncourse = ' + course + '\nurl = ' + url + '\naccess_token = ' + access_token);
}

module.exports = {assignments, discussions, announcements}
```

Also another advice to rename your functions, functions are verbs, not nouns, e.g. instead of `assignments` name it `getAssignments` or whatever it is doing.

UPD:

And looks like you are using wrong modules, Node.js uses CommonJS modules, so you have use `require` to import other modules unless you are using TypeScript or Babel.

Change your index.js file to

```
const express = require('express');
const{ assignments , announcements , discussions}
```

= require("./Fetch/fetchCalls.js");
var app = express();
app.use(express.json());
const PORT = 8080;
app.listen(PORT);

```
var guild;
var channel;

        

  app.all('/assignments',(request) => {assignments(guild = request.body.guild, channel = request.body.channel);});
app.all('/discussions',(request) => {discussions(guild = request.body.guild,channel = request.body.channel); });
app.all('/announcements', (request) => {announcements(guild = request.body.guild,channel = request.body.channel);});
```

Comment: Im not home yet so I can't test this, but do you know why it initiated works when I try this in 1 server, but if I keep the server on, a different server can't run these commands? @Azyrian

Comment: Tried it. This didn't work. Same problem. @Azyrian

Comment: Updated my comment, try again. @Zboyz

Comment: ReferenceError: require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use import instead
This file is being treated as an ES module because it has a '.js' file extension. To treat it as a CommonJS script, rename it to use the '.cjs' file extension. I am assuming I should change it to .cjs? @Azyrian